# html form post img to form preview

Tags: php, html

page1: new-user.php inputs 'name' 'age' and upload 'avatar',

```
// file new-user.php
<form method="post" action="localhost/preview-user.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input name="name">
        <input name="age">
        <input type="file" name="avatar">
        <input type="file" name="file_zip"> // any file ex: pdf
        <input type="submit" value="confirm">

</form>
```

new-user.php submit post to preview-user.php

page2: preview-user.php

```
// file preview-user.php
<form method="post" action="localhost/save-user.php"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div><?php echo $_POST['name'] ?></div>
   <input name="name" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST['name'] ?>">

   <div><?php echo $_POST['age'] ?></div>
   <input name="age" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST['age'] ?>">

   <img src="data:image/gif;base64,'
        .base64_decode(file_get_contents($_FILE['avatar']['tmp_name'])). '" />
   <input type="hidden" name="avatar"
       value="<?php echo file_get_contents($_FILE['avatar']['tmp_name']) ?>">//how work?

   <div><?php echo $_FILES['zip_file']['name'] ?></div>
   <input type="hidden" name="zip_file"
       value="<?php echo file_get_contents($_FILE['zip_file']['tmp_name']) ?>">//how work?
    <input type="submit" value="save">
</form>
```

page3: save-user.php

Solutions: create folder tmp/ to save img when submit new-user.php, then preview-user.php submit -> save-user.php 
move img from tmp/ to user/userid/{userid}_{filename}.gif, but i dont like create tmp/, when preview-user.php close browser, tmp/ img will not delete img.

```
<input type="hidden" name="avatar"
    value="<?php echo file_get_contents($_FILE['avatar']['tmp_name']) ?>">//how work?
<input type="hidden" name="zip_file"
    value="<?php echo file_get_contents($_FILE['zip_file']['tmp_name']) ?>">//how work?
```

Is it possible not make garbage img on server, when user on 
preview-user.php click close browers?
Or it possible not create tmp/?

I apologize for not being word-perfect in English.

Comment: Just convert your avatar file to base 64(use java script) then submit your form.After that you can  show it in preview section without use of temp folder .

Comment: buti use img avatar convert to thumbnail
$img = Image::make($avatar->path())->fit(320, 320, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->upsize();
            });
and how about file zip pdf if too large @dhamo

Comment: first your convert  base64 string to  image then you can do your thumbnail conversion.

Comment: @dhamo https://bunnycdn.com/blog/why-optimizing-your-images-with-base64-is-almost-always-a-bad-idea/  any other ways? not base64